# Position absolute is not relative to its SVG parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to put an element on `SVG` using the `position: absolute`, but the problem is that it not relative to the `SVG` element and it goes one level up. I simplified the code here and added `background` color to easily demonstrate it.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  position: relative;
}

.shape {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 250px;
}

#pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 text-center">
      <svg class="shape mt-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="560" width="588">
  <path fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" d="M294 3l291.246 211.603L474 556.983H114L2.754 214.603z"/>
</svg>
      <div id="pic">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mt8p3n4e/1/

The image should be within the red area (relative to the `SVG`). I should also say this is not an image but it's actually a card along with description which I simplified it as I saw some example about punting an image inside the `svg` tag.

Comment: I know, thats why I explained it, SO do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try like this.. svg inside you not add any other div

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-4 text-center">
      <div class="svg-image-col">
       <svg class="shape mt-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="560" width="588">
  <path fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="4" d="M294 3l291.246 211.603L474 556.983H114L2.754 214.603z"/>
</svg>
        <div id="pic">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  position: relative;
}

.shape {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

#pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.svg-image-col{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your position is not right because of margins that you have added to svg element ,you can add them to absoloute image

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.col-md-6 {
  position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

.shape {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 250px;
}

#pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    margin: 0 250px;
    margin-top: 3rem ;
}
```